# What does a 'changed' commit mean in git?

Tags: git

https://api.github.com/repos/linnovate/mean/commits/69ccd09e527894d8e0e992dceb6cb563dd759049

I thought if a file was `modified`, it would say `modified`. So what does `changed` mean? I tried googling, but it's a very... common term.

```
{
sha: null,
filename: "config/config.js",
status: "changed",
additions: 0,
deletions: 0,
changes: 0,
blob_url: "https://github.com/linnovate/mean/blob/69ccd09e527894d8e0e992dceb6cb563dd759049/config/config.js",
raw_url: "https://github.com/linnovate/mean/raw/69ccd09e527894d8e0e992dceb6cb563dd759049/config/config.js",
contents_url: "https://api.github.com/repos/linnovate/mean/contents/config/config.js?ref=69ccd09e527894d8e0e992dceb6cb563dd759049"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means something else changed on the file, such as permissions or the line feed style.

In this case it was the permissions.

You can see [here](https://github.com/linnovate/mean/commit/69ccd09e527894d8e0e992dceb6cb563dd759049) that the permissions changed from 100755 to 100644.

Comment: Other than permissions, what else could it be? And how do I see that change using the `github` API?

Comment: Line feeds apparently. No idea as to the API - it doesn't look like there's an option.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR** The status is 'changed' if "the mode of the file was changed or there are unknown changes because the diff was truncated"

I recently contacted GitHub's support about the documentation for the status field, this was their reply. The field was causing problems for our json parsing on a pull request with 300+ files changed.

> Thanks for reaching out. You're right -- the possible values are not documented. I'll mention this to the team so that they can consider updating the documentation.
>
> For now, here are the possible values:
>
> 'added' - file was added
>
> 'removed' - file was removed
>
> 'renamed' - file was renamed
>
> 'modified' - the content of the file was modified
>
> 'changed' - the mode of the file was changed or there are unknown changes because the diff was truncated (I believe this might happen for very large diffs)
>
> If you notice any other values -- let me know and I'll do some more digging.
>
> Hope this helps.